# AWS SimpleDB contains value

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to make a db query (AWS simpleDB) and want only things to return if they contain the `@` symbol somewhere in the email field. I am starting like this

```
select * from `myDomain` where email = _____
```

I just can't figure out what to put in that space.

I found this article which explains features and keywords of simpleDB but was unable to see anything here that could help me... http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1231

So if there are 3 items with emails 1."abc@def.com" 2. "1234" 3."asdf" then only "abc@def.com" should be returned because it contains `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from myDomain where email like '%@%'
```

Source:
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1231